# Doctrine inheritance and associations

Tags: symfony, inheritance, doctrine, entity-relationship, model-associations

I have entity **Image** with properties:

```
class Image {   

private $id
private $name;
private $mimeType;
private $size;  }
```

Now, I need to add new image type which will have **all** properties as existing class and some new properties like author name, external url, url to author... Let's call it **ExternalImage**. Existing images don't need these properties.

Then I need to add image property to **Event** class and it can be either Image or ExternalImage.

One other use case is that I need to list all images (both types at once, on some API endpoint).

My solution would be:

```
ExternalImage extends Image
 .. add new properties
```

and use SINGLE TABLE Doctrine's inheritance. And then add OneToOne association to Event class (adding image_id property).

```
<one-to-one field="image" target-entity="App\Common\Entity\Image">
```

1. is inheritance appropriate for this example? I don't see any other solution from my perspective. We have strong "is a" relation between Image and ExternalImage.
2. I am aware of performance issue with using STI entity as target entity of one-to-one association - image entity won't be lazily loaded when I fetch Event object. Can I do something about that?

Comment: tbh, I've yet to see a clear example of cases where STI is even slightly better than just a "merged" class. of course you can separate some logic into different classes, but as far as I can tell it's the *only* benefit, beyond that, you have additional class checks, weird mind bending and all the setup hassle. So, I'm really really suspicious of actually any kind of doctrine inheritance ;o/

Comment: You can do it by [Doctrine Inheritance Mapping](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.7/reference/inheritance-mapping.html)

Comment: @Jakumi hmm, but I don't like idea that Image (base image) has properties which it doesn't need/use. This type of image doesn't have external URL. I also need to track usage of Image/ExternalImage through application. What scares you most about Doctrine inheritance, lower performance?

Comment: it's not performance, but just ask yourself how much time you've already spent on this, and it's probably requiring more time when you face the problems you wouldn't have with just one class. you could still add a field "type" that contains some int with 0 for image and 1 for external image or whatever and you can track that. however, just because I haven't had any good experience with doctrine inheritance mapping so far, doesn't mean anything in the end. maybe I just didn't have the right mindset.